# How to upload file mvc6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want implement api that upload zip files.

My function working for text files but not for zip file.
Zip file is saved but can not be open.
Do you know whet is good aproach for this?

At client I call api in next action:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                        var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
                        fileContent.Headers.Add("X-FileName", fileName);
                        fileContent.Headers.Add("X-ContentType", file.ContentType);

                        var response = await client.PostAsync(url2, fileContent);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(nameof(this.Index));

        }
```

This is my api:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {

        var input = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
        var fileName = Request.Headers["X-FileName"];
        var fileType = Request.Headers["X-ContentType"];

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\" + fileName))
        {
            sw.Write(input);
        }

        await Task.FromResult(0);
        return new ObjectResult(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solutin:

On client API

```
        [HttpPost("{lastModified}")]
        public async Task<string> Upload(long lastModified)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                        var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
                        var archiveUrl = "path to api with 2 parameters {fileName}/{lastModified}";
                        var datasetResponse = await client.PostAsync(archiveUrl, fileContent);
                        var dataset = await datasetResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return dataset;
                    }
                }

                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot updated dataset to archive");
            }
        }
```

On server API

```
        [HttpPost("{fileName}/{lastModified}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string fileName, long lastModified)
        {           
            var dataSet = getDataSet(); 

            return new ObjectResult(dataSet);
        }
```